# TortoiseGit responding "/usr/bin/sh: git-lfs: command not found" when attempting diff of lfs tracked file

Tags: gitlab, tortoisegit, git-lfs

I am trying to perform a diff of a LabVIEW (.vi) file using TortoiseGit.  I get the following error:

```
Failed to checkout file "*****.vi" of revision ### to
"C:\Users\***\TortoiseGit\*****-###.vi".
libgit2 returned: External filter application exited non-zero (127) and reported:
/usr/bin/sh: git-lfs: command not found
```

I am using TortoiseGit 2.8.0.0 with a GitLab server.  I have lfs enabled.  Any file type that is tracked with lfs seems to have this problem.  The error message seems straightforward as to what the problem is, but it's not clear to me how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try and launch TortoiseGit after changing the `PATH`, adding:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin
```

The `git-lfs.exe` is in `%GH%\mingw64\bin`

```
./mingw64/bin/git-lfs.exe
```

That means TortoiseGit will be able to execute "`git lfs`" when launched with the proper `%PATH%` value.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  It's not clear to me how I launch TortoiseGit from command line when it's normally used as a shell extension.

Comment: However, taking your idea and adding `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin` to the path did resolve the problem!  If you want to modify your response to that effect or add a new one, I can make it as the answer.

Comment: @ChrisPurves Great! I have rewritten the answer accordingly.

Comment: And if it isn't there, how to get it? I've latest version of TortoiseGit.

Comment: @ChuckSavage Independently of TortoiseGit, you need to check where [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) itself is installed. You will find `mingw64/bin` in it.